# combining local storage items and outputting in paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, output, local-storage

I am storing in localStorage multiple records with this code:

```
    localStorage.setItem('LinkURL' + ranNr, rdsLinkURL);
    localStorage.setItem('LinkTitle' + ranNr, rdsLinkTitle);
    localStorage.setItem('LinkOrderURL' + ranNr, rdsLinkOrderURL);
    localStorage.setItem('OrderAmount' + ranNr, rdsOrderAmount);
```

Each record is a product in a shopping cart so when there are 3 products added into the cart there will be 12 records in local storage in 3 sets (each product has its own set).

I have learned today how to output one of the records that start with a certain text. I do this with the code below.

```
  let duffy = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(v => v.startsWith("LinkTitle"));
  duffy.forEach(z => $("body").append("<p class='" + localStorage.getItem(z) + "'></p>"));
```

The code above works and there are 3 paragraphs created. But now I want to fill the paragraph with the `OrderAmount` but I am not sure how to manipulate the above code to get that effect.

I forgot to mention that I am trying things: Will post that here as well.

```
  let duffy = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(v => v.startsWith("LinkTitle"));
  duffy.forEach(
    z => $("body").append("<p class='" + localStorage.getItem(z) + "'></p>")
  );

  let goofy = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(v => v.startsWith("OrderAmount"));
  goofy.forEach(
    g => localStorage.getItem(g)
    $('.' z).append(g)
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, I came up with another way to get what I wanted:

By combining everything that I needed into one item that got send to the localstorage I had no problem retrieving it and then separating it to make it work with the rest of the code.

The combination:

```
var rdsCombo = "("+rdsLinkTitle+")["+rdsOrderAmount+"]{"+rdsProductID+"}";
```

The output of this combination would look like this:

`(title)[4 x][25]`

The saving to local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('Combo' + ranNr, rdsCombo);
```

The retrieving from local storage

```
let ducky = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(a => a.startsWith("Combo"));
  ducky.forEach(
    b => $("body").append("<p class='quantity-verification qvid-" + count_one++ + "' style='display:none;'>" + localStorage.getItem(b) + "</p>")
  );
```

Extracting data from the retrieved local storage add

```
$('.quantity-verification').each(function() {
  var qvCombo = $(this).text();
  // Extracting Title
  var qvTitle = qvCombo,
  qvTitlepos = qvTitle.indexOf("(") + 1;
  qvTitle = qvTitle.slice(qvTitlepos, qvTitle.lastIndexOf(")"));
  // Extracting Quantity
  var qvQuantity = qvCombo,
  qvQuantitypos = qvQuantity.indexOf("[") + 1;
  qvQuantity = qvQuantity.slice(qvQuantitypos, qvQuantity.lastIndexOf(" x]"));
  console.log('qvQuantity:'+qvQuantity);
  // Extracting Product ID
  var qvProductID = qvCombo,
  qvProductIDpos = qvProductID.indexOf("{") + 1;
  qvProductID = qvProductID.slice(qvProductIDpos, qvProductID.lastIndexOf("}"));
  console.log('qvProductID:'+qvProductID);
}); // end of each function
```

Now with everything sliced and diced, I could use whatever I needed to create the effect from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could get each paragraph with querySelector, 
for instance:

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('selector for your paragraphs')
paragraph.forEach((p, i ) => {
const amount = goofy[i]
    p.innerHTML = amount
})
```

But it would be also a good approach to save every product with its own order amount.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. How should I implement your code? Should I remove certain parts of the original code above? Products are saved originally but this code is necessary when a payment fails the shopping cart is then automatically emptied. And I am now trying to go around that.

Comment: could you console.log your data? just to see a better picture of it. or have a link to your code. that would be helpful. Thanks